# Effect of change of orientation on Fragments

Tags: android

Are `Fragments` destroyed and recreated on orientation change (e.g. screen rotation) just like `Activity`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, normally [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) have similar lifecycle events as activities do. They also get destroyed and recreated on orientation change.

But it is possible to set a fragment to retain instance, which means that it survives the orientation change via the [setRetainInstance(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) methode. This introduces quite a lot of new problems, but sometimes it is still the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You as a developer can control this behavior. Check this piece of the official documentation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean).